# How do i code how to know if a turtle is moving?

Tags: netlogo

Im making a project for school and i need to know if a turtle has moved to do something for example if turtle moved make the oxygen level drop down by 1. i have just dont know what to use, this is my code:

```
to breathe
 if pcolor = blue [
  set  oxygenlevel oxygenlevel +5
  ]
if turtle = moving????
 set oxygenlevel oxygenlevel - 1
if oxygenlevel = 0 [
die
]
```

Comment: Where is your code about moving the turtle? The easiest way to do something like this is to have a piece of code that moves the turtle and decreases the oxygen within the same code block

Comment: Oh yes thank you! Didn't think of that at all.